# Write binary file from text string that represents hex bytes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binaryfiles

I have the following text string that represents hexadecimal bytes that should appear in file to create.

```
str = "001104059419632801001B237100300381010A"
```

I want to create a file that contains the above string in order when I open the created file with a Hex editor I see the same bytes

When I run this script

```
File.open("out.dat", 'w') {|f| f.write(str.unpack('H*')) }
```

it creates the file out.dat and when I open this file in a Hex editor contains this

```
5B2233303330333133313330333433303335333933343331333933363333333233383330333133303330333134323332333333373331333033303333333033303333333833313330333133303431225D
```

and I would like the content when I open the file in Hex editor be the same a text string

```
 001104059419632801001B237100300381010A
```

How can I do this?

I hope make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the string by *aligned bytes* in the first place.

```
str.
  each_char.     # enumerator
  each_slice(2). # bytes
  map { |h, l| (h.to_i(16) * 16 + l.to_i(16)) }.
  pack('C*')

 #⇒ "\x00\x11\x04\x05\x94\x19c(\x01\x00\e#q\x000\x03\x81\x01\n"
```

or, even better:

```
str.
  scan(/../).
  map { |b| b.to_i(16) }.
  pack('C*')
```

Now you might dump this to the file using e.g. [`IO#binwrite`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-c-binwrite).

Comment: Aleksei, thanks for helping me with this solution. Would your second solution with `scan(/../)` change if there are spaces between bytes in the hex string? I ask because the original string has spaces between bytes and I apply pre processing to remove them first and maybe with your solution could handle those spaces in the same step.

Comment: `scan(/..(?=\s)/)` should work out of the box (positive lookahead for two symbols followed by a space.) Also, if there are spaces, just use `split(' ')` instead of scan, it’s simpler and faster.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much again